# MySQL bitwise NOT operation isn't returning desired value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to convert some PHP code into MySQL code. Here's what happens:

In PHP:
I'm trying to use  bitwise not on a number and this is the result I get

```
var_dump(~(17998320));       Result: -17998321
```

The result in PHP is exactly what I need.

In MySQL:
When I try to do the same here I get a completely different answer.

```
select ~(17998320);      Result: 18446744073691553295
```

I guess it is something regarding BIGINT. How can I replicate the behaviour I see on PHP into MySQL?

Comment: Could you provide us the structure of the table and the insert statement ?

Comment: ~n is the same as (-1 -n) so you can use SELECT (-1 - number) AS result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was!

It's giving me the value in  2's compliment form. So you can get the right value by manually getting into it.

```
select -1 * (~((~(17998320)) - 1))
```

Thanks anyways for all the help :)